# Use PHP to shorten URL text from Facebook API

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook API to display posts on a web page from a particular Facebook account. When the Facebook user posts a message that contains a link with long URL text (i.e. < a href="http://www.google.com">http://thisisreallylongandeventuallybreaksmyfrigginlayout < / a >), it's breaking my layout.

Here's the PHP function I'm currently using to take the post from the Facebook API and turn any URLs into HTML links:

```
public function linkify($ret) {
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_\.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)*[\w]+)#i", "\\1<a href=\"mailto:\\2@\\3\">\\2@\\3</a>", $ret);
    return $ret;
    }
```

Can anyone help me to change the function so that it also truncates any long link text? I'm not talking about truncating the entire message, just any long text for links.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work by adding this line to my function:

```
$ret = preg_replace("/>(([[:alnum:]]+:\/\/)|www\.)([^[:space:]]"."{5,10})([^[:space:]]*)([^[:space:]]{5,10})([[:alnum:]#?\/&=])"."</", ">\\3...\\5\\6<", $ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have a regex for finding urls, so implementing this is a piece of cake. Here's a pseudo-code:

```
for each($matchedLink in $ret) {
  $ret = $ret.replace($matchedLink, "<a href='$matchedLink'>$(truncate($matchedLink))</a>";
}
```

(sorry, I am not a PHP coder, maybe it can be done in a smarter way)

Comment: I'm not cutting out www. I can't fix the layout, because it's a mobile layout. When the link is really long, the page gets zoomed out and is not 100% zoomed in. It's not broken, just not the way I want it displayed. I don't want to limit the text, only the url text which is causing the issue. I'm not creating the Facebook posts, so I can't use a URL shortener.

Comment: I didn't write the PHP code. I'm not good at regex...that's why I posted here. :) I would be grateful for the code.